# iOS Swift 3 - How to delete recently deleted image in Photos

Tags: ios, swift, image, swift3

I'm building an app in Swift 3, which imports an image from existing images and than deletes the original image.
The problem now is that the deleted image is moved in the folder Recently Deleted. So, how can I delete the picked image even from recently deleted folder?

Here is the code that I use to pick and delete the image.

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,
    UICollectionViewDelegate,
UICollectionViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var images: [UIImage] = [UIImage]()
    //var thumbnails:


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func addClick(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.click(sender)
    }
    @IBAction func click(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        let addActionSheet = UIAlertController.init(
            title: "Photo Source",
            message: "Choose a source",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.init(rawValue: 1)!)

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
            addActionSheet.addAction(
                UIAlertAction.init(
                    title: "Camera",
                    style: .default,
                    handler: {
                        (action: UIAlertAction)in
                        imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
                        imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
                        imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                )
            )
        }

        if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary)){
            addActionSheet.addAction(
                UIAlertAction.init(
                    title: "Photo Library ",
                    style: .default,
                    handler: {
                        (action: UIAlertAction)in
                        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                )
            )
        }

        addActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel ", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(addActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    /**
     *User picked a photo
     */
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        self.imageView.image = image
        self.images.append(image)

        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL
        let imageURLs = [imageURL]

        //Let's delete it now
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges(
            //CHANGE-BLOCk
            {
                let imageAssetToDelete = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: imageURLs, options: nil)

                PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(imageAssetToDelete)
        },
            completionHandler: {
                (success, error)in
                NSLog("Finished deleting asset. @", success ? "Success" : "Error")
        })
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    /**
     *Returns the number of cells to create.
     */
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 50
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 3

        cell.image.image = self.images[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - have you testing this code when take a photo with the camera. Your code will probably crash. You really need to avoid the use of `!`.

Comment: i think you should never delete a original image from the users camera roll. that is surprising and you will get angry customers. you can delete the wrong image if the user tap on the wrong image. and if you not leave it in the `recently deleted` it is much worse. instead on fixing your bug you should think about the safety for your customer.

Comment: always do a copy of an image and let the customer do the cleanup of left overs and have the risk delete the wrong image.

Comment: and what if your app crash at sometimes or has a malfuction in your app. and not saved the new image. then all data is lost. and you have more angry customers

Comment: this is a security app, so I'm just trying to reach the goal of the app. In addition, the user is asked for deleting the image and I will do this only if the user answers yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete photos from 'recently deleted' album, maybe you should show instructions for the user so they can go to the 'recently deleted' album, select all the photos in there and delete them.